# Competing risk analysis of interval data

Tags: r, package, intervals, survival-analysis

I study competitive risks and use R.
I would like to use the model in Fine and Gray (1999), A proportional hazards model for the subdistribution of a competing risk, JASA, 94:496-509.

I found the cmprsk package.

However, I have an “interval data” configuration with a starting time `t0` and an ending time `t1` for each interval, `t1` being the exit or the right censoring when I am in the last interval for a given entity. Here is an extract of the dataset

```
entity   t0   t1   cov
1        0    3    12
1        3    7    4
1        7    9    1
2        2    3    2
2        3    10   9
3        0    10   11
4        0    1    0
4        1    6    21
4        6    7    12
...
```

I do not find how to implement that with `cmprsk`, while it is implemented FOR EXAMPLE in the survival package (`Surv(time,time2,…)`).

Is it possible to do it with `cmprsk` or should I go to another package?
I know that there is a Stata package (`stcrreg`) doing it but I prefer working with R.

Comment: What format would you need to have data? Could you describe it for people who are not familiar with `Surv()`?

Comment: The question has a `stata` tag because you mention it, but it seems irrelevant in this case. Consider deleting it. Consider also giving a full citation if you're including a reference.

Comment: It seems that cmprsk needs only t1, where t0 and t1 are needed for an interval data configuration. Is there something that I miss in cmprsk that would allow the use of many intervals for the same entity.